# Arraylist equivalent of arraycopy

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am learning android and am trying to make an application which involves the Fourier Transform. I found some example code but it was for doubles and I want to use floats and an arraylist instead. I changed most of the code but do not know how to change the line of code with `arraycopy`. The code is as follows:

```
public static void fourierTrans(ArrayList<Float> array) {

    FloatFFT_1D fftDo = new FloatFFT_1D(array.size());
    float[] fft = new float[array.size() * 2];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, fft, 0, array.size());  //This line here
    fftDo.realForwardFull(fft);

    /*for(float d: fft) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }*/
}
```

Does anyone know an arraycopy equivalent for arraylists with floats?

Answer (score 2):

In this simple case, you can use the following idiom:

```
ArrayList<Float> myCopy = new ArrayList<Float>(array);
```

It will create a new `ArrayList<Float>` with all the values from your `array` argument.

Now for a more complex idiom, where you want to limit the index and size of what's copied:

```
ArrayList<Float> foo = new ArrayList<Float>();
foo.addAll(Arrays.asList(1f,2f,3f,4f,5f));
ArrayList<Float> bar = new ArrayList<Float>();
// here it copies the values from the other list, 
// but limits the size to the other list's size / 2 (rounded down)
bar.addAll(foo.subList(0, foo.size() / 2));
System.out.println(bar);
```

**Output**

```
[1.0, 2.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a copy constructor

```
ArrayList<Float> copy = new ArrayList<Float>(original);
```